# SSH into pi via wifi, use internet on pi via internet

Tags: networking, bash

Right now I'm sshed to my rpi via wifi, however I would like my pi to use the direct ethernet connection to connect to the internet. I was wondering how I would go about doing this...

Comment: Just unplug the WiFi dongle and connect an ethernet cable instead.

Comment: i should mention this is a pi3.

Comment: Then disable wifi and connect ethernet cable. Adapt `/etc/network/interfaces` to your needs.

Comment: Is it possible to stay connected via wifi + ssh and have the pi3 use the internet with ethernet?

Comment: That's a routing problem. If the default traffic from RPi should go over ethernet, you should set that as default gateway. see http://superuser.com/questions/331720/how-do-i-set-the-priority-of-network-connections-in-ubuntu or http://askubuntu.com/questions/263572/can-i-use-wifi-and-cable-ethernet-networking-at-same-time. But generally not related to raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the `%interface` scheme in **SSH** ?

You can do something like `ssh -l pi 192.168.50.1%eth0` I think it should work.

You are essentially telling which interface should you ssh into via the `%eth0` I tend to use it on my PC.

I have `wlan0` configured in ad-hoc mode and everytime I need to SSH into pis over the same interface I use:

```
ssh -l pi IPv6LLaddress%wlan0
```

It should work for IPv4 too.